# What is the point of putting "Deny from All" immediately before "Allow from All" in an Apache directive?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have seen many example `httpd.conf` files containing directives such as [this one from IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/op/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.Installation_Guide_with_OpenPages_Repository.7.0.0.doc/t_shi_configuring_apache_load_balancer_windows.html):

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

In fact, searching Google for the exact phrase ["deny from all allow from all"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22deny%20from%20all%20allow%20from%20all%22) returns almost 3 million results.

My understanding of this directive is that based on the specified `Order`, Apache will deny you access to `/server-status` no matter who you are, but then immediately override that decision and allow you access instead. Is this correct? Is there any functional (or even theoretical or philosophical) difference between the above directive, and this next one?

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Comment: These directives are so confusingly stupid that Apache [finally got rid of them in 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- I'm actually using 2.4 that was bundled with WAMP, so I guess I should change their Allow and Deny directives altogether! (That page you linked to shows that they are deprecated, not yet removed.)

Answer (score 2):

according to [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order):

ordering is one of:

**Allow,Deny**
First, all Allow directives are evaluated; at least one must match, or the request is rejected. Next, all Deny directives are evaluated. If any matches, the request is rejected. Last, any requests which do not match an Allow or a Deny directive are denied by default.

**Deny,Allow**
First, all Deny directives are evaluated; if any match, the request is denied unless it also matches an Allow directive. Any requests which do not match any Allow or Deny directives are permitted.

**Mutual-failure**
This order has the same effect as Order Allow,Deny and is deprecated in its favor.

in this case, *all* Deny directives are evaluated; if any match, the request is denied unless it also matches *all* Allow directives.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but why do you say that the request is denied unless it matches *all* Allow directives, when the documentation you quote says it's denied unless it matches *an* Allow directive? Either way, this doesn't really answer my question because the Allow directive that grants access to all hosts follows immediately after the Deny directive, superseding it in every case. So I still don't see the difference between the two `<Location>` directives in my question...

Comment: **default access state** is set to Deny, so when Deny is not set it means Deny from all as in your second configuration. So there is no difference between those configurations.